# find key value in object

Tags: javascript, json

I have the following object(Json):

```
 let object = {
"statusCode": 200,
"body": [{
        "id": "3",
        "externalId": "yehudakala4",
        "status": "active",
        "createdAt": "2018-11-14T08:36:50.967Z",
        "updatedAt": "2018-11-14T08:36:50.967Z",
        "firstName": "yehu",
        "lastName": "da",
        "email": "ye@g.com"
    }
],
"headers": {
    "x-powered-by": "Express",
    "access-control-allow-origin": "*",
    "content-type": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    "content-length": "189",
    "etag": "W/\"bd-Emx3/KChQLzf9+6bgFSHXPQgDTM\"",
    "date": "<<Masked>>",
    "connection": "close"
},
"request": {
    "uri": {
        "protocol": "http:",
        "slashes": true,
        "auth": null,
        "host": "user-management-service.dev.local:4202",
        "port": "4202",
        "hostname": "user-management-service.dev.local",
        "hash": null,
        "search": "?username=yehudakala4",
        "query": "username=yehudakala4",
        "pathname": "/v1/users",
        "path": "/v1/users?username=yehudakala4",
        "href": "http://user-management-service.dev.local:4202/v1/users?username=yehudakala4"
    },
    "method": "GET",
    "headers": {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "accept": "application/json",
        "content-length": 2
    }
}
```

}

given the following function:

```
let key = "protocol";
let value = "http:";
let x;
let res = false;
let findValue = function findValue(obj, key, value) {

for(let localKey in obj){
    if(obj.hasOwnProperty(localKey)){
        //console.log(localKey)
        if(localKey === key){
            res = obj[localKey] === value;
            return res;
        }
        else
        {
            let val = obj[localKey];
            if(typeof val === 'object')
                x = findValue(val, key, value);
                if (typeof x === 'boolean') {
                    return x;
                }         
            }
        }
    }
}

let rs = findValue(object, key, value)
console.log(rs);
```

there are two problems with this approach:

1. if the key does not exist in object, then the function returns undefine
2. if key appears more than one time, it check only for the first time

my goal is too check any occurrence of key and if the value of one of them does not match return false, if all match return true.

second, if key does not exist return false.

Comment: Instead of return the x you should define a array and push your result at there so you could return your list .

Comment: Also this can be a very good use of regular expression. Faster than loops would be to do JSON.stringify and then applying proper regex.

Comment: There is no [JSON](http://json.org) in the code you posted. Just a JavaScript object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed your function to get all values for a given key by including a `Set` as context in the recursion.

Then you check the `set` for a `single value that equals your value`.

See updated snippet.

Finally, as a side note, `Object.keys` will make your code leaner, as you won't have to check for `hasOwnProperty`.

```js
let findValues = function(obj, key, found) {
  for (let localKey in obj) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(localKey)) {
      let val = obj[localKey];
      //console.log(localKey)
      if (localKey === key) {
        found.add(val)
      } else {
        if (typeof val === 'object') {
          findValues(val, key, found)
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

function uniqueValue(obj, key, value) {
  let found = new Set()
  findValues(object, key, found)
  return found.size === 1 && found.has(value);
}

let object = {
  "statusCode": 200,
  "body": [{
    "id": "3",
    "externalId": "yehudakala4",
    "status": "active",
    "createdAt": "2018-11-14T08:36:50.967Z",
    "updatedAt": "2018-11-14T08:36:50.967Z",
    "firstName": "yehu",
    "lastName": "da",
    "email": "ye@g.com"
  }],
  "headers": {
    "x-powered-by": "Express",
    "access-control-allow-origin": "*",
    "content-type": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    "content-length": "189",
    "etag": "W/\"bd-Emx3/KChQLzf9+6bgFSHXPQgDTM\"",
    "date": "<<Masked>>",
    "connection": "close"
  },
  "request": {
    "uri": {
      "protocol": "http:",
      "slashes": true,
      "auth": null,
      "host": "user-management-service.dev.local:4202",
      "port": "4202",
      "hostname": "user-management-service.dev.local",
      "hash": null,
      "search": "?username=yehudakala4",
      "query": "username=yehudakala4",
      "pathname": "/v1/users",
      "path": "/v1/users?username=yehudakala4",
      "href": "http://user-management-service.dev.local:4202/v1/users?username=yehudakala4"
    },
    "method": "GET",
    "headers": {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      "accept": "application/json",
      "content-length": 2
    }
  }
}

let key = "protocol";
let value = "http:";

console.log(uniqueValue(object, key, value));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make a simple recursive function for this problem. Which will find and validate the value of the property. The below mention function in snippet will :

- return true if the property is found and all its occurrences have same value.
- return false if the property is not found or all its occurrences do not match.

This function currently supports only object, i.e it recursively check for the property only in objects and not inside arrays, we can further extend it to support arrays also.

```js
let object1 = { auth : "ok", response : { auth : "ok" }, check : { check1 : { check2 : {auth : "no"} } } };
let object2 = { auth : "ok", response : { auth : "ok" }, check : { check1 : { check2 : {auth : "ok"} } } };


function findAndValidateKey(obj, targetKey, value, res){
  for(var key in obj){
    if(obj.hasOwnProperty(key) && key === targetKey){
      if(res === undefined)
        res = true;
      res = res && (obj[key] === value);
    } else if(obj[key] instanceof  Object && !Array.isArray(obj[key])){
      let tempResult = findAndValidateKey(obj[key], targetKey, value, res);
      if(res === undefined)
        res = true;
      res = res && tempResult;
    }
  }
  return !!res;
}
console.log(findAndValidateKey(object1, "auth","ok", undefined));
console.log(findAndValidateKey(object2, "auth","ok", undefined));
```

You can also implement a simple non-recursive solution for this problem, by using a `Stack` data structure.

```js
let  object1 = { auth : "ok", response : { auth : "ok" }, check : { check1 : { check2 : {auth : "no"} } } };
let object2 = { auth : "ok", response : { auth : "ok" }, check : { check1 : { check2 : {auth : "ok"} } } };

function findAndValidateKey(object, targetKey, value){
  let res = true, found = false;
  let stack = [JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(object))];
  while(stack.length){
    let obj = stack.pop();
    for(var key in obj){
      if(obj.hasOwnProperty(key) && key === targetKey){
        res = res && (obj[key] === value);
        found = true;
        if(!res)
          break;
      } else if(obj[key] instanceof  Object && !Array.isArray(obj[key])){
        stack.push(obj[key]);
      }
    }
    if(!res)
      break;
  }
  res = res && found;
  return res;
}

console.log(findAndValidateKey(object1, "auth","ok"));
console.log(findAndValidateKey(object2, "auth","ok"));
```

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is to initialize an `array` to get all the `values` that are part of the same `key`, and then in the end check if all these `array` are equal to the searched `value`, using:

```
let rs = matches.every(m => m == value);
```

This is how should be your updated `function`:

```
let matches = [];
function findValue(obj, key) {
  if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    matches.push(obj[key]);
  }
  for (k in obj) {
    if (Array.isArray(obj[k])) {
      obj[k].forEach(el => findValue(el, key));
    } else if (obj[k] && typeof obj[k] == "object") {
      findValue(obj[k], key);
    }
  }
}
```

**Demo:**

```js
let object = {
  "statusCode": 200,
  "body": [{
    "id": "3",
    "externalId": "yehudakala4",
    "status": "active",
    "createdAt": "2018-11-14T08:36:50.967Z",
    "updatedAt": "2018-11-14T08:36:50.967Z",
    "firstName": "yehu",
    "lastName": "da",
    "email": "ye@g.com"
  }],
  "headers": {
    "x-powered-by": "Express",
    "access-control-allow-origin": "*",
    "content-type": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    "content-length": "189",
    "etag": "W/\"bd-Emx3/KChQLzf9+6bgFSHXPQgDTM\"",
    "date": "<<Masked>>",
    "connection": "close"
  },
  "request": {
    "uri": {
      "protocol": "http:",
      "slashes": true,
      "auth": null,
      "host": "user-management-service.dev.local:4202",
      "port": "4202",
      "hostname": "user-management-service.dev.local",
      "hash": null,
      "search": "?username=yehudakala4",
      "query": "username=yehudakala4",
      "pathname": "/v1/users",
      "path": "/v1/users?username=yehudakala4",
      "href": "http://user-management-service.dev.local:4202/v1/users?username=yehudakala4"
    },
    "method": "GET",
    "headers": {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      "accept": "application/json",
      "content-length": 2
    }
  }
}

let key = "protocol";
let value = "http:";
let x;
let res = false;
let matches = [];

function findValue(obj, key) {
  if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    matches.push(obj[key]);
  }
  for (k in obj) {
    if (Array.isArray(obj[k])) {
      obj[k].forEach(el => findValue(el, key));
    } else if (obj[k] && typeof obj[k] == "object") {
      findValue(obj[k], key);
    }
  }
}

findValue(object, key);
let rs = matches.every(m => m == value);
console.log(rs);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    let obj = {
    "statusCode": 200,
    "body": [{
            "id": "3",
            "externalId": "yehudakala4",
            "status": "active",
            "createdAt": "2018-11-14T08:36:50.967Z",
            "updatedAt": "2018-11-14T08:36:50.967Z",
            "firstName": "yehu",
            "lastName": "da",
            "email": "ye@g.com"
        }
    ],
    "headers": {
        "x-powered-by": "Express",
        "access-control-allow-origin": "*",
        "content-type": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        "content-length": "189",
        "etag": "W/\"bd-Emx3/KChQLzf9+6bgFSHXPQgDTM\"",
        "date": "<<Masked>>",
        "connection": "close"
    },
    "request": {
        "uri": {
            "protocol": "http:",
            "slashes": true,
            "auth": null,
            "host": "user-management-service.dev.local:4202",
            "port": "4202",
            "hostname": "user-management-service.dev.local",
            "hash": null,
            "search": "?username=yehudakala4",
            "query": "username=yehudakala4",
            "pathname": "/v1/users",
            "path": "/v1/users?username=yehudakala4",
            "href": "http://user-management-service.dev.local:4202/v1/users?username=yehudakala4"
        },
        "method": "GET",
        "headers": {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            "accept": "application/json",
            "content-length": 2
        }
    }

}
let arrOfFound = [];
let key = "protoco";
let value = "http:";
let x;
let res = false;
let findValue = function findValue(obj, key, value) {
    JSON.last
    for(let localKey in obj){
        if(obj.hasOwnProperty(localKey)){
            //console.log(localKey)
            if(localKey === key){
                res = obj[localKey] === value;
                arrOfFound.push(res);
                //return res;
            }
            else
            {
                let val = obj[localKey];
                if(typeof val === 'object'){
                    x = findValue(val, key, value);
                    if (typeof x === 'boolean') {
                        arrOfFound.push(x);
                    }   
                }     
            }
        }
    }        
}
function checkKeyValue(obj, key, value){    
    findValue(obj, key, value)
    if(arrOfFound.length == 0){
        return false;
    }else{
        arrOfFound.forEach(element => {
            if(element == false)
                return false;            
        });
    }
    return true;
}
res = checkKeyValue(obj, key, value)
console.log(res);
```

Comment: the only thing I am not happy with is the fact that the findValue function uses an external array for storing the true and false results. I couldn't find a way of returning the array from inside the function without stopping the function in the middle.